# Move and replace files depending on the name with C#

Tags: c#

I want to move files  depending on there name from one folder to the other. 
What I want to achieve with that is that I only select these specific files from my export folder and replace them in my destination folder. And the items in the destination folder are the key so I want only these or else if the files already exist in the destination, replace them.

```
private static void CopyPaste()
{
    var pstFileFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyFolderTest/";
    var searchPattern = "*.docx";
    var soruceFolder= "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyFolderTest/Test/";

    // Searches the directory for *.pst
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, searchPattern))
    {
        // Exposes file information like Name
        var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        // Gets the user name based on file name
        // Sets up the destination location
        var destination = soruceFolder+ theFileInfo.Name;
        File.Move(file, destination);
    }
}
```

The source destination is: **soruceFolder** Origin is: **pstFileFolder**

The issue that I face is that I can not control what is copied it seems that my code is getting all files and not checking if these files exist in the sourfolder

Comment: Can you describe the problem you have with this code? In particular. it is not clear what is the target destination and the source destination

Comment: There is no question in your question! Can you explain what is the problem you are having?

Comment: You might want to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @KrisVandermotten No thanks that's fine ... I shall skip on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the destination folder to see if it includes your file like below:

```
 private static void CopyPaste()
 {
var pstFileFolder = "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyFolderTest/";
var searchPattern = "*.docx";
var soruceFolder= "C:/Users/chnikos/Desktop/CopyFolderTest/Test/";

// Searches the directory for *.pst
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(pstFileFolder, searchPattern))
{
    // Exposes file information like Name
    var theFileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    // Gets the user name based on file name
    // Sets up the destination location
    var destination = soruceFolder+ theFileInfo.Name;
    if(File.Exist(destination))
    {
       File.Delete(destination);
    File.Move(file, destination);
    }
}
}
```

It deletes the file in the destination folder if it exist and move your file. So if the file doesnt exist in the destination folder it does nothing ;)